# Cannot find module '_debugger' while using jasmine-debug or jasmine-node-debug

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have few tests that I have written using jasmine. I want to debug those tests and so I am using jasmine-debug module

```
sh-3.2# jasmine-debug
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '_debugger'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/jasmine-debug/node_modules/node-inspector/lib/debugger.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

I am using npm version : 5.6.0 and node version : 8.9.4

I kind of figured out that node-inspector does not seem to be compatible with the new version of Node but how do I get around debugging jasmine tests.

Other option I tried was Karma but there am using Bookshelf.js which is making it difficult to browserify.

I will be glad if anyone can help me to find an approach to debug Jasmine Tests.
Since I have just begin I can even switch to Mocha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a answer but alternative solution:

I also had a similar issue but I used IntelliJ IDEA and also node plugin for IntelliJ IDEA 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-mocha.html